# Spingboot CORS error only for Multipart POST

Tags: spring-boot, cors

Hello am facing a peculiar issue

I have enabled CORS on my Springboot API Server with following configuration

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

All my POST requests are working except an API for image upload. Its implemented as

```
@PostMapping(value = "/profiles/{id}/image")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void uploadProfileImage(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
    this.userService.uploadProfileImage(id, file);
}
```

On browser I see the OPTION for this request succeeding but the actual POST being made but hanging out and the console the displaying this error.

[image: Options call on console]

The error is

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:10000/users/profiles/1/image. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
```

The API does works correctly when used from PostMan so I think the issue is with CORS configuration and not actual API logic

Any pointers? Have tried adding @CrossOrigin to controller and specific API without any success.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. I am using angular 7 and angular http component. Had to change my post method from

```
uploadImageFile(file: File, id: number) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        return this.http.post(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/users/profiles/${id}/image`, formData);
    }
```

to

```
uploadImageFile(file: File, id: number) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        return this.http.post(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/users/profiles/${id}/image`, formData, {
            // This is required to manage post multipart updates
            headers: {}
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this bean in your configuration to support CORS:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access- Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```