# Configure Spring for CORS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm trying to configure Spring for CORS in order to use Angular web UI:

I tried this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.datalis.admin.config")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer conf = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        conf.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return conf;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("127.0.0.1");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Apache server with Angular FE is running with Wildly server on the same server so I configured 127.0.0.1 for source.

But still I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://123.123.123.123:8080/api/oauth/token' from origin 'http://123.123.123.123' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
auth:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Second way that I tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("resource_id").stateless(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSources() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

With the second configuration I get `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
auth:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: Just as a side note, you might want to consider setting the precedence to `bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` instead of zero.

Comment: Now I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53863603/10426557

Comment: @JonathanJohx I get Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://123.123.123.123:8080/api/oauth/token' from origin 'http://123.123.123.123' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: Any other proposals how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell `Spring Security` to use the CORS Configuration you created.

In my project I configured `Spring Security` in this way:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/protected/**")
        .authenticated()
     //Other spring sec configruation and then:
    .and()
        .cors()
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())

}
```

Where `corsConfigurationSource()` is:

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        boolean abilitaCors = new Boolean(env.getProperty("templating.oauth.enable.cors"));
        if( abilitaCors )
        {
            if( logger.isWarnEnabled() )
            {
                logger.warn("CORS ABILITATI! Si assume ambiente di sviluppo");
            }
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8180"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(  RequestMethod.GET.name(),
                    RequestMethod.POST.name(), 
                    RequestMethod.OPTIONS.name(), 
                    RequestMethod.DELETE.name(),
                    RequestMethod.PUT.name()));
            configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token", "x-requested-with", "x-xsrf-token"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Auth-Token","x-auth-token", "x-requested-with", "x-xsrf-token"));
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        }
        return source;
    }
```

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: I get again Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'http://123.123.123.123:8080/api/oauth/token' from origin 'http://123.123.123.123' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` Any other ideas?

Comment: From what I see I understand that: you must configure cors source with the IP address 123.123.123.123 more over the AJAX. Did you add also the IP address? Did you modify the CorsConfigurationSource by adding the right IP addess? Put on TRACE spring security logs

Comment: In your `logback.xml` file add a spring logger like this one  `<logger name="org.springframework.security" level="TRACE"></logger>`

Comment: ok, I will try later. Do you see issues in my Spring-boot/Spring Security configuration?

Comment: I'm not Spring boot expert but it seems to me all OK except the fact that cors config is commented

Comment: From what I see your IP is 212.75.28.84; did you configure this IP address too?

Comment: This is my home IP. I don't think that I need to add it into CORS.

Comment: Well you should. It's the IP who tries to invoke the REST API.

Comment: ok, but into production I can's add every end client into CORS configuration. Let's try to add `*`?

Comment: In production you MUST NOT add any excpetion. You should configure your Apache Web Server in order to serve all requests under same domain otherwise you can risk very huge hacker attacks; this is the reason in my code I have a properties variable

Comment: Let's focus on this? If I configure Apache to serve all requests under same domain do I need to configure CORS in Spring?

Comment: No you must not configure CORS. According to JS all requests are in same origin and it's safe to serve all them

Comment: ok, I will try this then. One more question: What if I run the Angular application on apache server, not on the client machine? (Classic application served page by page from the server)

Comment: I think it’s the best thing to do.... I usually do in this way.... all static resources served by Apache

Comment: ok, I will test it today and let you know. Can you share more how do you use Angular?(Server setup and etc.)

Comment: did you solve the issue by configuring your web server?

Comment: no, Angular for some reason can't use Apache as proxy.

Comment: I added description here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331671/configure-apache-as-proxy-to-forward-requests-to-wildfly-server

Answer (score 6):

Your allowed origin is 127.0.0.1 but your client side has the ip 123.123.123.123. Try to change this:

```
config.addAllowedOrigin("127.0.0.1");
```

To this:

```
config.addAllowedOrigin("123.123.123.123");
```

Comment: Hi Raphael! Welcome to StackOverflow. I editted your post to format the code -- for future reference, code blocks are formatted by indenting them with four spaces.

Comment: You can try to add on your client the header "with credentials: true". You can do it on angular adding a interceptor on the http client. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615205/angular-2-http-withcredentials

Answer (score 3):

This is my working `@Configuration` class to handle CORS requests used only in dev environment.

```
@Configuration
//@Profile(PROFILE_DEV)
  public class CorsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
      return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
          @Override
          public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
              registry.addMapping("/**")
                  .allowedOrigins("*")
                  .allowedHeaders("*")
                  .allowedMethods("*");
          }
      };
  }
}
```

You have also to configure Spring Security to ignore `HttpMethod.OPTIONS` used by preflight request (as the exception you mentioned)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  //...
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring()
            //others if you need
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }

}
```

Because when you use cors you have [Simple Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) and [Preflighted Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) that triggers an `HttpMethod.OPTIONS`

Comment: I use also Spring security. Is this going to work for Spring Security?

Comment: updated answer with spring security OPTIONS configuration

Comment: I tried your proposal combined wit the proposal from @Angelo Immediata but still I get the same issue. Any additional idea how to solve it?

Comment: My solution doesn't need to add other stuff. Try to leave the code as i explained, just be sure `@Configuration` classes are correctly loaded. Tell me if you still have exception

Comment: I tested only your code. Unfortunately the issue is not fixed.

Comment: can i see your configuration classes?

Comment: Today I will upload on GitHub minimal working example.

Comment: I added my configuration here: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Spring_test

Comment: this is good because now CORS configuration is working but for some reason `      web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");` is not taken... Now you have a 403 FORBIDDEN on preflight request. You need to allow in spring security all your OPTIONS method

Comment: I tried to add this: `http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()` But now I get `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: remove `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()` and leave OPTIONS configuration only in `CorsConfiguration` class

Comment: I get during deployment: `Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: At least one mapping is required (i.e. authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated())` Can you extend a little bit what I need to set for HttpSecurity http

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187072/discussion-between-valeriomc-and-peter-penzov).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `@CrossOrigin` class level in your controller class like below

```
@CrossOrigin
public class SampleController {
    // Your code goes here
}
```

annotation to your rest controller class

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use a WebMvcConfigurer, and in the addCorsMappings method set the CORS configuration.

Somethingo like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9798")
            .allowedMethods("POST", "GET")
            //.allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            //.exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
            .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Here there is a link with a fully functional Spring with CORS project, just download and run it.

https://github.com/reos79/spring-cors

It has a html page (person.html) this page does nothing but call the service on the port (9797). So you need to load this project twice, once on port 9797 to load the service and the other on port (9798). Then on you browser you call the page person on the server localhost:9798 and it will call the service on localhost:9797, in the file application.properties I configured the port.

Comment: do you know do I need to add some configuration in Apache and Angular?

Comment: Here is the Wildfly config file using your configuration: https://pastebin.com/TzXPsNwt

Comment: Did you remove the Bean public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSources() ?  and Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I will try again with clean setup later.

Comment: Here is the result from the second attempt: https://pastebin.com/q5eRqSz8

Comment: I missed this in my code: `http
        .cors().and()
     .csrf().disable() 
     .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
     .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();`

Comment: That is due to authentication problems, replace your method with this, just to try Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     
     http
     .cors().and()
     .csrf().disable() 
     .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

Comment: No positive result.

Comment: it's difficult because I dont have your complete project. The project I gave you it's just to run, you dont need an appserver or something else, it just work. I suggest you that compare both projects and see whats is different

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your bean name to corsConfigurationSource removing the "s"

Documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cors

> // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource